# Unknown column 'Recipe.userId' in 'field list' in typeorm

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

[image]

Why i get this error? userId is come from where?

This my user.entity.ts
[image]

And it's my recipe.entity.ts
[image]

Comment: i add new code
@ManyToOne(type => User,user => user.recipe)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'author_id', referencedColumnName:'id'})
user: User

npm can run but the data still not show i want show the name of users

Answer (score 1):

change query `Receipe.userId` to `Receipe.user: {id: ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Change your query with the same name in your Entity, in your case  `Recipe.user` instead of `Recipe.userId`.

Even if in the database the foreign key is called `userId`refer to your entity.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As long as the names are not mismatched you will have to

1. re-generate migration files
2. reseed your database